# How to add audio to a h264 video stream using gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I can successfully stream HD video using following pipelines:

streame server:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="Gravity.2013.720p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.mp4" ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay  pt=96 ssrc=0 timestamp-offset=0 seqnum-offset=0 pt=96 !  gdppay ! tcpclientsink host=192.168.1.93 port=5000
```

client:

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcpserversrc host=192.168.1.93 port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

I want to add the audio stream too. 
I guess it is possible to use a different port and tcpserver/tcpclient combination to stream audio parallel to video. But I am not certain, how gstreamer would synchronize two streams properly to play the movie in the client end. Apart from this method, are there any other methods? such as muxing two streams before and demuxing it in client end?